# infinite Union of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How to Show that an infinite union of compact sets is not necessarily compact ?

It can be done for finite union of set but how to do these for infinite union of compact sets..

PLease Help

Comment: I really like the answer Isaac gave in a different thread: "Every point set is compact. Every set is a union of points. If the union of compact sets is compact, every set is compact. Give any example of a noncompact set you have seen in class."

Comment: It sounds good now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take $I_{n}=[-n,n]$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am not getting this, then how to comment on its compactness  ?

Comment: @pratik: Each $I_{n}$ is compact. But is $\mathbb{R}$ compact?

Comment: @pratik: $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact because it is not bounded. Recall that $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ compact iff closed and bounded. (This is the Heine-Borel Theorem).

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. What is $\bigcup_n [\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n]$?

Comment: You don't need the $\frac{1}{n}$ in one of the intervals to show this, right?

Comment: Yes you do, $\bigcup_n [\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]=[0,1)$ which is not compact since it isn't closed but every element lf the union is compact.